# Having trouble capitalizing first letter of a blockquote

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("span").wrapInner("<blockquote><q></q></blockquote");
    
    $("blockquote").css("border-top", "1px solid grey");
    $("blockquote").css("border-bottom", "1px solid grey");
    $("blockquote").css("padding", "5px 0 5px 0");
    $("blockquote").css("font-size", "15px");
    

    
        
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Get going fast</h2>
        <p>In just the first 6 chapters of this book, you'll learn more about web development than 
        you can from most full books.</p>
        <p>It's true! In fact, <span>by the end of the crash course in 
        Section 1, you'll be developing web pages the way today's best professionals do.</span>
        That means you'll be using HTML5 semantic elements to mark up the structure of the 
        content on the page and CSS to format and lay out that content.</p>
```

I found a solution for how to capitalize the first letter in a string but I don't think I implemented it correctly. I get an error saying "blockquote.substr is not a function." Here is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("span").wrapInner("<blockquote><q></q></blockquote");

$("blockquote").css("border-top", "1px solid grey");
$("blockquote").css("border-bottom", "1px solid grey");
$("blockquote").css("padding", "5px 0 5px 0");
$("blockquote").css("font-size", "15px");

var blockquote = $("blockquote");
blockquote.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + blockquote.substr(1);

    
}); // end ready
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: `blockquote` is a jQuery object and you are using substr on it?

Comment: One problem is that you've told jQuery to wrap what's inside a [`span`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) ([phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)) with a [`blockquote`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) element, which is only allowed where [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2) is allowed. So the browser is having to fix an invalid structure, which is likely to cause trouble.

Comment: You could do something like `blockquote::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }` with pure css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `blockquote` variable is an HTML element, not a string. First, get it's `textContent` and call `substr` on it. You also need to set its text content to your result.

```js
blockquote.textContent = blockquote.textContent.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+blockquote.textContent.substr(1);
```

Comment: While essentially you are correct, in OPs code `blockquote = $("blockquote")` is a jquery object, **not an HTML element** - so would be either `blockquote[0].textContent` or (easier) `blockquote.text()` (or not use jquery to get the DOM element)

Comment: That would blow away any HTML elements inside the blockquote, including the `<q>` that was *just* added.

Comment: Am I writing this out correctly? I'm not getting an error anymore but the first letter is still not capitalized:

blockquote.text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + blockquote.text().substr(1);

Comment: What did you write?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter without shift and forgot to enter the code. I re-edited it to include the code I wrote out. When I had blockquote.text() = blockquote.text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+blockquote.text().substr(1); I received an invalid left-hand side error.

Comment: When you used `text()` you're assigning a function, whereas with vanilla (my answer) you assign a property

Comment: You should use `textContent`

Comment: Hey expressj123, I used textContent and it worked but now the quotes are gone. Any tips?

Comment: YOu want to discuss in chat instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need using [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20the%20value%20of,as%20well%20as%20element%20nodes.) from jQuery or [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) from vanilla javascript

example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const blockquote = $("blockquote"); // yep, i like using this
  const text = blockquote.text()
    .trim(); // do u need new lines? nope...

  blockquote.css({ // u can using object to pass all css styles
    "border-top": "1px solid grey",
    "border-bottom": "1px solid grey",
    "padding": "5px 0 5px 0",
    "font-size": "15px"
  });
  blockquote.text(text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1));
}); // end ready
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <blockquote>
    hello wolrd
    </blockquote>
  </body>
</html>
```

And if you wanna capitalize all words:

```js
// create a function to capitalize some word
const capitalize = value => value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.substr(1);

// split into array based on spaces, and capitalize all words to finally join to make a full capitalized string
blockquote.text(text.split(' ').map(i => capitalize(i)).join(' '))
```

Whats happend if you have a multiple items with te selector? you can using `each` like this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      const blockquote = $("blockquote"); // yep, i like using this
      
      blockquote.each((index, element) => {
        const text = $(element).text()
          .trim(); // do u need new lines? nope...

        $(element).css({ // u can using object to pass all css styles
          "border-top": "1px solid grey",
          "border-bottom": "1px solid grey",
          "padding": "5px 0 5px 0",
          "font-size": "15px"
        });
        $(element).text(text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1));
      })
      
    }); // end ready
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <blockquote>
    hello wolrd
    </blockquote>
    
    <blockquote>
    wow
    </blockquote>
  </body>
</html>
```

> **Tip #1:**
>
> In jQuery u can get text with `element.text()` and set text with
> `element.text('some text')`.
>
> **Tip #2:**
>
> In jQuery u can using `element.css('prop', 'value')` to apply one
> style, but if u have more than one, you can try `element.css({ ... })`
> to make it more simple and clear..
>
> **Tip #3**
>
> In javascript one string is an array of chars, so you cat pick the first element with index like `text[0]` or `text.charAt(0)`.
>
> **Tip #4**
>
> If you work with html and the text have new lines(`\n`), you maybe wanna remove it... please using trim or regex `/\n+/g` te
> remove it
>
> **Tip #5**
>
> In javascript you can split string based on a specific char using split. It separate all items and returning a array of string, so
> it make more easy to iterate.
>
> **Tip #6**
>
> In jQuery u can using CSS selector to pick some element:
>
> 1. `#my-element` - pick element with specific id
> 2. `blockquote:nth-child(0)` - matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings
> 3. `blockquote + blockquote` - blockquote after another  `blockquote`
> 4. `blockquote:first-child` - first element...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have two blockquotes on the page and when I use the solution you provided is combines the two. I just want to capitalize the first one. Additionally when I used your solution it stripped the quotes. Thanks again. Any chance you can help with these issues?

Comment: man, you using it for one specifc, only need set the CSS selector

Comment: I writing some tips with css selectors